# Removing elements that have consecutive dupes in Elixir list

Tags: list, filter, elixir

I have a list of numbers in **Elixir**, and I want to remove the duplicates, but only for the consecutive dupes.

For the following input list: `[1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,2,2]`.

The result should be: `[1,2,1,3,2]`.

Comment: `Enum.dedup/1`?

Comment: Nice, I realize that `Enum.dedup_by/2` works better in my case, because the values on the list will be `Map` not `Integer`

Comment: Do you want to write an answer @Dogbert?

Comment: @EduardoPereira are the maps not exactly equal that you had to use `Enum.dedup_by/2`? I've posted an answer which includes maps as elements of the list. @narrowtux done, thanks!

Comment: Nice, because my maps needed a different filter :) but thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enum.dedup/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#dedup/1) does exactly what you want: it replaces consecutive duplicate elements with only one instance of it and returns the remaining elements in a list.

```
iex(1)> Enum.dedup([1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2])
[1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
```

This works on all values that compare equal with `===`, including maps:

```
iex(2)> Enum.dedup([%{a: 1}, %{a: 2}, %{a: 2}, %{a: 2}])
[%{a: 1}, %{a: 2}]
```